# split string with space as index separator

Tags: c#, .net

I'm taking users input from one textbox where multiple choices will be separated by commas, like:

Peter Gabriel, John Snow, Lebron James

I'm separating these strings like

```
string[] inputAuthors = txtAuthors.Text.Split(',');
```

now I want from `inputAuthors[0]` (Peter Gabriel) to select separated Peter and Gabriel. As I see the only way is to split this strings as space as index of separation, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: how about another split, similar to the one you already know?

Comment: yep, but how to use space value?

Comment: ' '  or " "  <--------------- not rocket science

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var namesSeparated = inputAuthors[0].Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
String[] names;
names = inputAuthors[0].Text.Split(' ');
```

?